# How to morph this code snippet into Java 8 where logic depends on index value?

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I have this code that I would like to see it in Java 8 flavor:

```
List<Double> outcome = ....
int step = data.size / 20;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  Instance inst = data.get(i * step).getInstance();
  if (inst.isPresent()) 
    outcome.add(100);
  else 
    outcome.add(0.0);
```

For me, it is easy to transform the code into Java 8 streams but I don't know how to implement the `data.get(i * step)` part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `IntStream`, which is "*a sequence of primitive int-valued elements supporting sequential and parallel aggregate operations*".

For example:

```
IntStream.range(0, 20)
         .forEach(i -> {
              Instance inst = data.get(i * step).getInstance();
              outcome.add(inst.isPresent() ? 100d : 0d);
          });
```

As @AlexisC. suggested, this can be reduced to a one-liner:

```
List<Double> outcome = 
         IntStream.range(0, 20)
                  .mapToObj(i -> data.get(i*step).getInstance().isPresent()? 100d : 0d)
                  .collect(toList());
```

Comment: ... or `List<Double> outcome = IntStream.range(0, 20).mapToObj(i -> data.get(i*step).getInstance().isPresent()? 100d : 0d).collect(toList());` for a one-liner.

Comment: Nice one, @AlexisC. Thanks for the note :)

Comment: @AlexisC. Also, that is beautiful! Would u please add it as answer for future reference?

Comment: @Chiron assylias already post it with a slightly different version; the map operations are just splitted in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative solution that does not mutate the list but uses a collector instead (side-effect free code is generally recommended when using streams, especially if you may parallelise them in the future):

```
List<Double> outcome = IntStream.range(0, 20)
                        .mapToObj(i -> data.get(i * step).getInstance())
                        .map(inst -> inst.isPresent() ? 100d : 0d)
                        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Really thanks. I wish that I could choose two accepted answers. I went with your solution :)